# Importing CSV to MySQL without losing an auto-increasing field's data

Tags: sql, mysql, import

I imported data from MySQL to a CSV. Now I am trying to import it into another machine's MySQL. But I want to preserve the original auto-increased `id`'s values.

I tried this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/region.csv'
INTO TABLE regions
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES

(id,name,parent_id,level)
```

But this didn't work. Any help?

Comment: Can you say in what way it didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "auto increase" field you speak of is "auto increment". To preserve it, temporarily alter the table to not use AUTO INCREMENT on the ID column, then once imported, alter it back.

E.g

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11)  UNSIGNED  NOT NULL;
```

Then:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: i was thinking is there some switch to disable it a while,in sqlserver there is a ddl to slove this problem when to bulk insert data to db

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create the target table with a column 'id' without auto increment property, load the csv file, and then add auto increment attribute to the column.